# Windows 10, MobaXterm, "bash: /bin/chmod: cannot execute binary file"

Tags: mobaxterm

> bash: /bin/chmod: cannot execute binary file.

Similar to another question here on the boards.

I tried answer suggestion, but to no avail:

1. uninstalled MobaXterm
2. re-installed MobaXterm

Still get:

> bash: /bin/chmod: cannot execute binary file

The same response when I try other commands, like `ls`, `mv`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to restart from a clean install please try this procedure:

- Open MobaXterm.
- Run `open /` command from a local terminal => the Windows Explorer should open in your `slash` folder.
- Close MobaXterm.
- Rename your slash folder at Windows Explorer from `slash` to `slash-old`
- Open MobaXterm
- Verify if it now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, and spent good couple hours trying to solve this.

The solution was to delete the profile, and then Run as Administrator - apparently when you don't, Cygwin is unable to create proper symlinks to its utilities.

Comment: I want to second this.  Deleting the profile and not running Moba as admin the next time resulted in the same non-working situation for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy, quick solution is to either delete, or rename, the *MobaXterm/slash* folder.  Then restart MobaXterm.  Upon restart, MobaXterm will rebuild the *slash* folder, and all is well.
I am guessing that a contributing cause, at least in my case, is that I have set NotePad++ as the "favorite" editor, and tend I toggle back and forth between opening the files from MobaXterm and opening them directly from the MS Windoze context.  This is probably confusing MobaXterm.

Comment: really?  `Windoze`?